# ARKit How to stop flickering or How to position node towards camera,

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have created Wall with SCNPlane. on that plane I am adding another Plane where User point the device

But because of both plane has same position newly added plane is flickering.

So How can I keep distance from wall node and plane node

how i add plane node.

```
let hitTestScene = self.sceneView.hitTest(self.sceneView.center, options:[SCNHitTestOption.categoryBitMask : 16])
 if let first = hitTestScene.first  {
    if first.node.name == NodeNames.wallNode {
       let value = MathHelper().getMeasurementBetween(vector1: lastNodePosition, and: first.worldCoordinates)
          let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: CGFloat( value) , height:  CGFloat(value)))
           node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
           node.name = "Plane1"
           node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1)
           node.eulerAngles = first.node.eulerAngles
           node.position = lastNodePosition

           self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

       }
 }
```

Plane in red is continually    flicked  (appear - disappear )

[image]

I have tried `node.position.z -= 0.2` but it is not working and node position changes completely   because of `node.eulerAngles`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure it out.

by setting rendringOrder and `readsFromDepthBuffer` I was able to stop that flick effect

```
extension SCNNode {
    func renderOnTop() {
        self.renderingOrder = 2
        if let geom = self.geometry {
            for material in geom.materials {
                material.readsFromDepthBuffer = false
            }
        }
        for child in self.childNodes {
            child.renderOnTop()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope some can  use  it if same issue

Comment: if i do this on my text, my text seems to be not solid anymore, but yes, no flickering, but it doesn't look like a solid text anymore :(